# Initializing a static final field in static initializer does not give me a compile-time-constant (Java)

Tags: java, constants, static-variables, static-initialization

I try to use the annotation @MultipartConfig(location=Test.MY_CONST) in a servlet.

When i use **Code 1** from below, it works just fine. When i use **Code 2** from below, then i get the following output when compiling:

> error: attribute value must be constant
> @MultipartConfig(location=Test.MY_CONST)

**Code 1**

```java
public class Test {
    public static final String MY_CONST = "/constant/path";
}
```

**Code 2**

```java
public class Test {
    public static final String MY_CONST;
    static {
        MY_CONST = "/constant/path";
    }
}
```

**Questions:**
I have a few questions which all boils down to "*What's going on here?*"

1. What is the difference(s) between **Code 1** and **Code 2**?
2. Do i get this error because @MultipartConfig needs a compile-time-constant, and assigning a compile-time-constant to `MY_CONST` in the static initializer does not make `MY_CONST` a compile-time-constant?
3. What is printed by `System.out.println(Test.MY_CONST)`, in case of **Code 2**, if i change the value of `MY_CONST` with reflection?

Comment: If it's initialized in the static block, you could have had an `if` or other statement that changes the value of it depending on some internal/external property. It's not a constant then.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a "final" variable. A "constant" variable cannot be changed. It is initialized directly also.

Comment: I'm not trying to change a final variable. I'm trying to use the final variable MY_CONST as i compile-time-constant. But i cannot do that if i use __Code 2__ to initialize the value of that constant.